# Nonlinear Differential Equation of High Degree

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Any help, please? How can I start to solve them? I tried to use $y'=p$. Also I tried $x=e^x$ and so many methods, but I couldn't reach them to the end. I always got blocked in the middle. Thanks in advance.

First equation: $$6x^2y-6y'^2+(12x^2-3x^3)y'+x^5-6x^4=0.$$
Second equation: $$x=\frac{y\ln y}{y'}-\frac{y'^2}{y^2}$$ with $y>0$.

Comment: What is the difference between X and x?

Comment: There is no difference it is x in both , sorry it's because the caps lock button was on

Comment: thank you for the edit @SagarM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second differential equation:
$$x=\frac{y\ln y}{y'}-\frac{y'^2}{y^2}$$
$$x=\frac{\ln y}{(\ln y)'}-{((\ln y)')^2}$$
Substitute $u=\ln y$:
$$x=\frac{u}{u'}-{u'^2}$$
Multiply by $u'$:
$$xu'=u-u'^3$$
This DE is of the form:
$$u=xu'+f(u')$$
This is [Clairaut's differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_equation).

Comment: Thank you so much Aryadeva

Comment: You're welcome Crisitna @Cristina

Answer (score 0):

FIRST EQUATION :
$$6x^2y-6y'^2+(12x^2-3x^3)y'+x^5-6x^4=0.$$
By inspection one can see a particular solution :
$$y=\frac13 x^3\quad\implies\quad y'=x^2$$
$6x^2(\frac13 x^3)-6(x^2)^2+(12x^2-3x^3)(x^2)+x^5-6x^4=$

$=2x^5-6x^4+12x^4-3x^5+x^5-6x^4=0.$

This draw us to the change of function :
$$y(x)=\frac13 x^3+u(x)\quad\implies\quad y'=x^2+u'$$
$$6x^2(\frac13 x^3)-6(x^2+u')^2+(12x^2-3x^3)(x^2+u')+x^5-6x^4=0.$$
After simplification :
$$6x^2u-3x^3u'-6u'^2=0$$
The change of $x$ into $-x$ doesn't change the equation. This draw us to the change of variable $X=x^2$  which leads to :
$$u(X)=X\frac{du}{dX}+4\left(\frac{du}{dX}\right)^2$$
This is a Clairault's differential equation.

SECOND EQUATION :
$$x=\frac{y\ln y}{y'}-\frac{y'^2}{y^2}$$
Since Aryadeva already answered there is no need to reapeat the method of solving.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very helpful!